# Transparency/opacity issues in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8, opacity

I'm developing a 'one page' website for a customer.
The website displays as I want it in most browsers however I'm experiencing problems in a specific combination of Internet Explorer 8 installed on Windows XP.

Because of a combination of requirements from the customer and the design of the graphical designer different elements are placed on top of eachother and need to fade in or out based on navigation.

All works fine in browsers like IE9&10 (Including IE8 document property in developer tools), Chrome and also IE8 on Win2K8 server.

However in IE8 it seems like the transparency of invisible elements is inherited by 'would be' visible siblings at the same position.

I've searched for different solutions and have tried different things like:

```
opacity: 0;
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
-filter: alpha(opacity=0);
```

also with an additional but mostly unneccesary:

```
display: block;
```

or

```
zoom: 1;
```

But none of the above does the trick.

Has anyone experienced, or solved, this problem before.
Or is fading multiple elements at the same position in IE8 just not the right way to go.

See this fiddle for my intended functionality:
http://jsfiddle.net/6HZGw/11/

PS. I tried to post an image of what exactly was my problem but since I've just registered this is not possible as a spam prevention measure.

So here is the link to the problem:
http://img338.imageshack.us/img338/4458/ie8f.png

And the link to the expected view:
http://img255.imageshack.us/img255/8391/chromeothers.png

Comment: do you have a url for the site?

Comment: [link](http://www.facentraal.nl)

Comment: why is the font transparent?

Comment: that's basically the problem i'm having ;) in IE8 it's transparent (among other things) in for example chrome it's not

Comment: you have the font set to transparent, why not use javascript and show hide the content?

Comment: Because show/hide is essentially the same as display none/block and has no css transition to as far as i can tell. I believe that the text inherits its transparency from the containing block element, correct me if i'm wrong. But that one's transparent because of css fade by opacity transition (see fiddle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE8's opacity filter is really awful. It kinda works some of the time, but it's riddled with bugs and gotchas. jQuery makes it slightly less painful, but even then it's easy to get caught out by one of the quirks.

I don't have IE8 or XP available to test it on right now, but I have been down this path myself and suffered similar results, particularly when dealing with multiple elements, and even more particularly when those elements are a mix of text and graphics.

As I say, I can't try it out for myself right now, but my guess is that you've hit one of those problems that just can't be resolved. So I would suggest looking for alternative solutions.

In our case, after a lot of work, we ended up completely abandoning the idea of fading the elements in and out because of this, and switched to a tactic of sliding them out from behind other elements. The effect was similar enough that the customer was happy, and it worked in all browsers.

Comment: It would of course be very frustrating if it would turn out to a complete redesign but I'm affraid that there is no other option since there does not seem to be a viable solution to this problem. In you're case, did you mimic the fade in/out animation with slides or did you just completely redesign the page (placement of elements and such) to work with slide animations? Do you have an example of a slide animation similar to fade in /out?